# PHP CLI ram management

Tags: php, memory, ram

I made a php script that runs in background, this script takes around 10mb on the RAM, & I've multiple scripts running at a time, Im afraid to get out of ram. 
I've already optimized my code to set variables and objects to null.

Is there a way to manage this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please, add your code. Actually is impossible to understand if it's efficient or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it has become much better, PHP is not very suitable for long-running processes in my opinion, but calling [`gc_collect_cycles();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) on a regular basis can do wonders, especially if you have do deal with a lot of data (import scripts and so on).

Without code I can not offer much more help.

Comment: The php script that i wrote uploads files on FTP servers, which takes alot of time, and there are multiple of these scripts running on the same time. I'm going to try gc_collect_cycles() & look for improvements .. Thank you.